# Have 2 buttons at same time c++

Tags: c++, winapi, button, createwindow

everyone !
I'm trying to have 2 buttons at same time in a C++ application and each other does 2 different actions.
Code :

```
MSG msg;
HWND m_hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
HWND hwndButton1 = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("B1"), WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_FLAT, 100, 100, 100, 30, m_hwnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(m_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
HWND hwndButton2 = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("B2"), WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_FLAT, 200, 100, 100, 30, m_hwnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(m_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
ShowWindow(hwndButton2, SW_SHOW);
ShowWindow(hwndButton1, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(hwndButton2);
UpdateWindow(hwndButton1);
while(1)
{
    GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    if((HIWORD(WPARAM)) == BN_CLICKED and ((HWND)LPARAM) == hwndButton1)
    {
        printf("1st clicked");
    }
    if((HIWORD(WPARAM)) == BN_CLICKED and ((HWND)LPARAM) == hwndButton2)
    {
        printf("2nd clicked");
    }
}
```

but it gives me a CE in the 'if' : "expected primary-expression beore ')' token"(x2, for each 'if'). Can you help me ?

Comment: I fixed your 'and' to '&&"

Comment: `and` is not a keyword in C++. Perhaps you meant `&&`.

Comment: `and` actually _is_ a keyword in a conforming C++ implementation -- it's an alternative keyword for the && operator ([cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and))

Comment: and actually is a keyword in C++ ... Either HIWORD or BN_CLICKED are unknown/undefined.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It [actually is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) a keyword.

Comment: What is this source code suppose to do? Why don't you handle the appropriate Windows messages?

Comment: Even if it is a keyword, it's about as confusing as trigraphs (just looking at the comments here), so I'd advise to avoid it.

Comment: @AmitG.: It isn't in Visual Studio 2017, which fully conforms to C++17. That statement, as written, is wrong. Besides, neither `HIWORD` nor `BN_CLICKED` are keywords. They are identifiers, the former a function-like preprocessor macro, the latter a symbolic constant, also a preprocessor symbol. None of that is related to MFC.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not supported. You cannot attach child windows (your buttons) to a parent window you do not own. You do not own the console window.

Comment: @AmitG. FWIW `&&` and `and` both work in C++

Comment: @NathanOliver See the screenshot from a real MFC project (generated with Create New Project directly from the IDE) compiled on VS2017 15.7.5 set to C++ latest draft (inc C++17). Look at the output screen. I marked with red line & an arrow to shorten your time.

Comment: @AmitG.: *Real MFC* is probably something I'd subscribe to pre-C++98 C++. Stop polluting your environment; set up a fresh C++ Console application project in Visual Studio, and take it from there. Using the alternative `and` operator is fully supported by Visual Studio 2017. P.S.: I see that you finally deleted your proposed answer. I assume that you found out, that everyone telling you that it were supported was in fact correct.

Comment: @AmitG.MSVS is not known for it's standard conformance.  Just because you get a squiggly line from it doesn't mean it is illegal.  The C++ standard says it is legal so it is.  It doesn't matter what MSVS says about it.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Visual Studio 2017 is **fully** conforming to C++17 (with some C++20 experimental features, like coroutines).

Comment: @IInspectable Sweet.  Looks like they finally got Expression SFINAE working

Comment: @AmitG.: An MFC project likely sets the `/Za` flag, i.e. enable language extensions. What that really means is: Stop being a C++ compiler, and adapt to code that was written 2 decades ago. The question isn't asking about an MFC project, so stop using your MFC experiences as if they applied here. They simply don't. Set up a fresh project, and verify for yourself. General advice here: If you find yourself in a hole, stop digging.

Comment: @AmitG.: Can't you just let it rest? Visual Studio 2017 allows use of the alternative `and` operator in a C++ project. That's what this question is about. If it fails for an MFC project, using undisclosed compiler options, then so be it. We don't care. It's not applicable here. The 'bug' you identified, ain't.

Comment: @IInspectable (after more research) The reason for the yes/no error is the ***/permissive-*** flag in the compile command-line. With ***/permissive-*** no error. By default, the /permissive- option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and later versions. It is not set by default in earlier versions. In any case, there is no ***/Za*** in the compile command-line.

Comment: @AmitG.: Is there any reason you keep posting an deleting comments? My inbox shows 14 (!) new messages from you. If you want to investigate what isn't related to this question, I would kindly ask you to keep me out of it.

Answer (score 3):

`WPARAM` and `LPARAM` are types. You should use `msg.wParam` and `msg.lParam` instead:

```
if((HIWORD(msg.wParam)) == BN_CLICKED and ((HWND)msg.lParam) == hwndButton1)
```

Comment: And this is a very atypical usage anyway, it would generally go in the window procedure where you would use wParam directly. Remember that lots of windws code creates hidden windows, here you test for whether the wParam matches without even considering whether the message is for the right window.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: The code is also testing against the windows' `HWND`. `HWND`s are unique per [desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573.aspx), and messages cannot cross desktop boundaries. Hidden windows are not an issue when applying this test.